# Infinite recursion error with and conditions?

Tags: prolog

I have the following facts and rules in my database.

```
above(b, a).
above(c, b).
above(d, c).
above(X,Y):-above(X,Z),above(Z,Y).
below(X,Y):- above(Y,X).
```

This works as intended for the positive case so that if I query,

`above(c,a).`

The return value is True. However, when I tried the query below expecting a False,

`above(a,c).`

I received the message,

```
  Stack sizes: local: 0.2Gb, global: 16Kb, trail: 3Kb
  Stack depth: 2,839,964, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 12
  Probable infinite recursion (cycle):
    [2,839,964] above(a, _1394)
    [2,839,963] above(a, _1420)
```

My understanding was that since there is no atom X associated with `above(a,X).`, and indeed this query returns a False, the first condition of my rule would not be met and that would be sufficient to conclude the query is False. This appears not to be the case. How can I set up the rules so that it does return a False while still working as intended for the positive cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `above(a, X)` does not match the first three clauses (the facts), it enters the fourth clause, `above(X, Y) :- ...`. The very first thing you do after that is `above(X, Z)`, which is to say, `above(a, Z)`. This then tries the first three clauses, which fail, and then it gets to `above(X, Y)` again. This is the source of your infinite recursion.

The solution is to separate your rule from your facts by renaming one of them, such as:

```
is_above(b, a).
is_above(c, b).
is_above(d, c).

above(X,Y):- is_above(X,Z), above(Z,Y).
below(X,Y):- above(Y,X).
```

This way you do not have unbounded recursion, `above` must make some forward progress before it recurs.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Your suggestion worked, I just had to make sure I kept the ```above``` facts as well as the ```is_above```.

Comment: Glad to help, hope it makes sense!